# Rails 3 pulling data from another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a client request on one of my projects where they want to be able to enter a url and have it pull in some information form the site who's url they entered and save it in the database.

So the user enters: http://www.example.com/2342342 and my controller visits that site, and gets the content of the first `<h1>Tag</h1>` on the site and saves this in the database.  Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it? Would I use some rails commands to do it, or something else, like jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nokogiri is a great parser and can work directly with an url.

So two steps there:

1. Instantiate a Nokogiri object with the url as param
2. Parse the html page to get what you expect

Find instructions here: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html

Because you'll work with another website, keep in mind two advice:

- wrap your queries so that you can rescue if the website is down
- consider using ajax request because it could be long

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but ajax wont work since it's a cross domain request. I think you have the right idea to use Nokogiri.

Comment: The point is to use an ajax request to your own controller which will handle the Nokogiri's stuff wrapped in a begin/rescue.

Answer (score 3):

I would checkout the Railscast here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri

It's explained very well on how to use Nokogiri and scrape content from other sites.